# I only see a part of the transferred amount with my viewkey

Tags: cold-storage, viewkey

I send an XMR amount from an exchange to a cold address. Using the tool xmrchain.net/tx/... I wanted to check if the transaction went well with the viewkey.

I only see about 1/3 of the amount as incoming transactions. Can someone explain if this is ok or what went wrong?

Thx

Comment: Did you send the full amount in separate transactions? If so, you need to check them separately and add them up.